# obtaining proximity matrix from random forest for unsupervised scenario in R

Tags: r, clustering, random-forest, unsupervised-learning

I recently came across the concept of proximity matrix in random forests (see for example this [great StatQuest video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6EXPYzbfLCE)). This can easily be obtained in the regression or classification scenario like so:

```
library(dplyr)
library(randomForest)
library(datasets)

data(iris)

model <- randomForest(
    Species ~ ., 
    data=iris,
    proximity=TRUE
)

head(model$proximity)
```

I am just wondering, if one could also obtain it without specifying a target as such? I tried:

```
library(dplyr)
library(randomForest)
library(datasets)

data(iris)

temp <- iris %>%
    select(
        Sepal.Length
        , Sepal.Width
        , Petal.Length
        , Petal.Width
    )

model <- randomForest(data=temp, proximity=TRUE)
```

without success. I read somewhere that a fudge like this may be the solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(randomForest)
library(datasets)

data(iris)

temp <- iris %>%
    select(
        Sepal.Length
        , Sepal.Width
        , Petal.Length
        , Petal.Width
    ) %>%
    mutate(
        fudge = 1
    )

model <- randomForest(fudge ~., data=temp, proximity=TRUE)

head(model$proximity)
```

Not sure, if this is acceptable? Thanks!

PS:

I followed this and the results using the "fudge approach" actually make sense:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(dplyr)
library(randomForest)
library(datasets)

data(iris)

temp <- iris %>%
    select(
        Sepal.Length
        , Sepal.Width
        , Petal.Length
        , Petal.Width
    ) %>%
    mutate(
        fudge = 1
    )

model <- randomForest(fudge ~., data=temp, proximity=TRUE)

distance.matrix <- as.dist(1-model$proximity)

mds.stuff <- cmdscale(distance.matrix, eig=TRUE, x.ret=TRUE)

## calculate the percentage of variation that each MDS axis accounts for...
mds.var.per <- round(mds.stuff$eig/sum(mds.stuff$eig)*100, 1)

## now make a fancy looking plot that shows the MDS axes and the variation:
mds.values <- mds.stuff$points
mds.data <- data.frame(Sample=rownames(mds.values),
  X=mds.values[,1],
  Y=mds.values[,2],
  Status=iris$Species)

ggplot(data=mds.data, aes(x=X, y=Y, label=Sample)) + 
  geom_text(aes(color=Status)) +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab(paste("MDS1 - ", mds.var.per[1], "%", sep="")) +
  ylab(paste("MDS2 - ", mds.var.per[2], "%", sep="")) +
  ggtitle("MDS plot using (1 - Random Forest Proximities)")
```

[image]

PPS:

The section:

Unsupervised learning

Here: [https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ebreiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm)

explains it but TBH I do not fully understand what it means. Could someone please help?

Comment: See it: http://gradientdescending.com/unsupervised-random-forest-example/

Comment: @bbiasi thanks. The interesting thing is, one can also use this for mixtures of numerical and nominal variables (I think).